# Import error: No module named gspread or csv?

Tags: python, csv

I am working with a Google spreadsheet, and am trying to use Python 2.7 to convert the spreadsheet data to a CSV file.

When I attempt to run the script I receive:

```
Import error: No module named gspread.
```

When I take out the `gspread` portion, then I receive:

```
Import error: No module named csv.
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

```
import csv
import gspread

g=gspread.login('skiesgoinggreen@gmail.com', 'e-mail_password')

docid = "0AgNp9UJ4CX93dHl3RW9GRXJDS3kxaXRJMGNqWmhQWVE"

spreadsheet = g.open_by_key(docid)

for i, worksheet in enumerate(spreadsheet.worksheets()):

    filename = docid + '-worksheet' + str(i) + '.csv'

    writer = csv.writer(open(filename, 'wb'))

    writer.writerows(worksheet.get_all_values())
```

Answer (score 6):

Try the following:

1. Check you don't have a file named csv.py
2. Check you have python version >= 2.3
3. Install gspread with:

   `pip install gspread`

Comment: Thank you for quick response to my question elyase.  I was able to install python 2.3 and made sure there was not a csv.py file on my computer.  I did have a question on your step 3.  I was not sure where I enter pip install gspread.  Is it within the IDLE for python, the command line, or somewhere different?  Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Sorry if I mislead you, I meant Python greater than 2.3 (when the csv module was introduced) so if you had 2.7 that was already ok. `pip` should be run in the command line. If it doesn't work you can also try `easy_install gspread`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's get some clarification here... the "pip install gspread" command is only for linux.

If you are on Windows, you need to have these modules in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages

I thought CSV module came built-in but I checked and I don't have gspread, you need to download it and place the gspread.py file in the aforementioned directory.

Comment: Thank you CMDoolittle for your suggestion. Unfortunately I am still having problems with the same module not found error.  Please let me tell you what I have done after reading your post so you can tell me where I have gone wrong. I first went to the website St8rm13_sk13z5 where I saved the file gspread-0.0.13.tar to C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages. I then ran the script and then received the gspread module not found error. I'm sure it is something simple that I am missing. As you can tell I am extremely new to Python.  Thank you so much for your help and sharing of your expert python knowledge.

Comment: Ok some things... about the CSV module, this comes prepackaged with python 2.7.  What elyase meant when he said "check you don't have a csv.py file" is that you shouldn't have a csv.py file that YOU'VE created in the working directory as the script you're trying to get working.  In order to import the CSV module, however, you must have csv.py in C:\Python27\Lib (this is where I have it).  As far as gspread, if you have a file called gspread.py in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\gspread, then you should be able to import it into your script.  Do you need to unzip the download?  I dunno.